# Does jQuery Validate support IE8? Mine does't work in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I tried the latest version 1.15, but it doesn't work in IE8, i'd like to know if it supports IE8...

One strange thing is that with version 1.14, IE7 and IE9 runs well while IE8 failed.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery#Browser_support

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5942327/jquery-validation-not-working-in-ie7-ie8 it has provide some solutions.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? What errors are you seeing? WHat's not working? What happens in debug mode?

Comment: jquery version is v1.11.3, there was no errors in the console.. @charlietfl

Comment: Still not any information regarding what's not working and if you have tried in in debug mode or even how you are configuring it

Comment: @charlietfl how can I configue this plugin in debug mode?

Comment: First option http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/   just set `debug:true`

Comment: @charlietfl many thanks! im going to try this

Comment: Are you using the actual browser?   FYI - using "ie8 mode" is not the same as using Ie8; it's not a true emulation.  Microsoft provides free HD images with various browsers pre-installed that you use within a virtual PC for testing purposes.

Comment: @Sparky I did use "ie8 mode" in ie 11

Comment: That's your problem then.   You must test in actual browser.

Answer (score 0):

As per the OP's comments:

> I did use "ie8 mode" in ie 11

You cannot use "ie8 mode" in another version of Explorer to do any meaningful testing.  **These "ie" compatibility modes are not browser emulators**, they are simply fall-backs for older or non-compliant code.

For proper testing, you must use an emulator or a real browser.  Microsoft provides free virtual machines and other tools for this purpose.

**[Free tools from Microsoft for IE browser testing.](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/)**